# How to pass URL parameter values in Apache Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat

I'm little new to the apache tomcat. Please find the detail given below.

I have following parameters and its values.

1. client_id : c66728
2. store_id : s126

Then I need to pass those values in the URL like this : URL : http://server_ip:8080/client_id/c66728/store_id/s126/

My Question : How I can pass those variables like the URL above, If I try now, it shows the following error.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What environment are you working in? You might want to post a bit of code: Are you looking for a pure servlet solution? REST? Any library that you're using, that the expected answer should use? And what's the relevance of the `apache`, `npm` and `build` tags that you use? (read their descriptions)

Comment: @OlafKock environment is CentOS, and using Apache tomcat to deploy. Using "npm run build" to build the project.

Comment: The apache tag, as you can see in the description, is for Apache httpd. And I'd rather see code that doesn't run than knowing what you use to build it, which is largely irrelevant for debugging the problem (at least without the code). You didn't answer the middle ones of my questions above. Please edit your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out the path to the folder apache is serving files from. Generally under /var/www/
2. Find out the default document (by default it might be index.php) probably is the only document in the path previously found (/var/www/)
3. The server must be configured to enable module mod_rewrite
4. To treat the request in that default document you need to have had set up your .htaccess file in that folder to AllowOverride All
5. Then you can create a rewrite rule (placed in .htaccess file) to redirect everything to the same page anypage.php
6. Inside your anypage.php you can split the url in / to get field value array.

the easiest way to go would be to install a framework or a library to handle it for you.